# Every LR(0) grammar is SLR(1) but vice versa need not necessarily be true, why?

Tags: compiler-construction, lr-grammar

Every LR(0) grammar is SLR(1) but vice versa need not necessarily be true, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, an SLR(1) grammar can resolve shift-reduce conflicts that exist in a corresponding LR(0) grammar. Take the example grammar on Wikipedia's [SLR parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_LR_parser) page (which explains this at a lower, more rigorous level):

1. S → E
2. E → 1 E
3. E → 1

When an LR(0) parser is parsing an **E** and a "1" is the next input symbol, it could recognize **E** and reduce (rule 3) or it could shift in order to parse a following E (rule 2). Because it can't look ahead, an LR(0) can't determine which to do. This becomes more obvious if we look at the [items](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Items) the LR(0) could be processing when it encounters a "1" (the end-of-string symbol has been added):

- E → 1 • E $
- E → 1 • $

The first would require a shift, the second requires a reduce.

With the above grammar, an SLR(1) grammar can look ahead one symbol and determine which action to take. **E** can only be followed by $, so a reduce action is only valid at the end of string. This corresponds to the second item, where you can see the next symbol is a "$".

For another example grammar that is SLR(1) and not LR(0), see Fegaras' [notes for CSE 5317/4305](http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node20.html) at the University of Texas.